# Why does Wikidata query "ignore" my OPTIONAL properties?

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I am trying to gather information on castles, palaces and other types of grand houses in the Netherlands and have written the following **Wikidata** query, which includes several optional properties as the extent of the available information varies from item to item:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?type ?nativelabel ?architect ?stlye ?date ?starttime ?opening ?owner ?admin ?GeoNamesID ?coords WHERE {
  ?item (wdt:P17/(wdt:P131*)) wd:Q55;
    wdt:P31/wdt:P279 ?type.
  FILTER((?type = wd:Q23413) || (?type = wd:Q16560) || (?type = wd:Q879050) || (?type = wd:Q751876) || (?type = wd:Q12292478) || (?type = wd:Q16823155))
  OPTIONAL {
    ?item wdt:P31 ?type;
      wdt:P131 ?admin;
      wdt:P1566 ?GeoNamesID;
      wdt:P1705 ?nativelabel;
      wdt:P127 ?owner;
      wdt:P571 ?date;
      wdt:P580 ?starttime;
      wdt:P1619 ?opening;
      wdt:P84 ?architect;
      wdt:P149 ?style;
      wdt:P635 ?coords.
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
LIMIT 3000
```

The query returns **1212 results**, which are all relevant, but the optional properties are being ignored. The only information that is returned are `item`, `itemLabel`, and `type`. As I am not a regular SPARQL user, I cannot spot the mistake in my query and would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Why do you have `?item wdt:P31 ?type` in the `OPTIONAL` block? Is the variable name an oversight (as you already use it to restrict which types the result must have), or is there a reason for having it?

Comment: Oh, yes, I got rid of that, but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get a result if *all* of the graph patterns in the `OPTIONAL` block match.

If you want to match each pattern on its own, you have to place each pattern in its own `OPTIONAL` block:

```
OPTIONAL {?item wdt:P31 ?type .}
OPTIONAL {?item wdt:P131 ?admin .}
OPTIONAL {?item wdt:P1566 ?GeoNamesID .}
OPTIONAL {?item wdt:P1705 ?nativelabel .}
OPTIONAL {?item wdt:P127 ?owner .}
OPTIONAL {?item wdt:P571 ?date .}
OPTIONAL {?item wdt:P580 ?starttime .}
OPTIONAL {?item wdt:P1619 ?opening .}
OPTIONAL {?item wdt:P84 ?architect .}
OPTIONAL {?item wdt:P149 ?style .}
OPTIONAL {?item wdt:P635 ?coords .}
```